# Unhandled exception when trying to run my WorkerRole on using Windows Azure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-worker-roles

I've just created my first Microsoft Azure application, I wrote a simple WorkerRole program which should print in every second a message on the console.
I constantly get the following exception when running my program:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WaWorkerHost.exe
Additional information: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge'.

The build succeeds without any error message. I also tried to rebuild several times the project, but this wasn't helping...
I'm using a 32-bit operating system, with Azure SDK and Visual Studio 2010 installed.
How can I fix this problem and run my program without getting this exception?

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of the Azure SDK do not [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn407359.aspx#BKMK_VS2010) Visual Studio 2010. You might want to try [using](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) the new Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.